# How do i get data given row, width, depth coordinay of an flatten 3d array stored in a list

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am currently trying to navigate in a 3d array i've flatten to a 1d list.

How do i given row, width and depth navigate in a flatten 3d array?

Comment: z * rsz * csz+y*rsz+x will access element x in row y of plane z if rsz and csz are the row and column sizes resp. and your indexes start at 0.

Comment: what is ... 
zrszcsz+y*rsz+x?

Comment: Edited. It interpreted the * * as markup...

Comment: what is rsz , csz ?

Comment: As I said row size (number of elements in a row) and csz is number of elements in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have your 3D array defined as:

```
I = 2
J = 3
K = 4
a = np.arange(I*J*K).reshape(I,J,K)

array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

Flattened array defined as:

```
a_flat = a.flatten()
```

To get the same element as a[0,1,2] from a_flat, you can do

```
a_flat[0*J*K + 1*K + 2]

#check
print(a[0,1,2])
print(a_flat[0*J*K + 1*K + 2])
```